# Watch espn/fox sports go/NBC sports live extra Don't work ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, flash, chromium

For some reason I can't get anyone of these sites to work in firefox, chrome, or chromium. I have flash installed and can play youtube and never have a problem playing videos on other websites. When I sign on to the sites and click the event I want to watch the video player never opens... This is the same on all 3 sites. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen? Any chance upgrading to 16.04 will fix it? My laptop is duel booted with windows 10 so I can switch os to use these sites but i'd rather not have to switch os to just these applications.

Comment: They might be using a DRM solution like widevine, which does not work in Linux. It's the same with HBO / HBO Nordic. You could look into do. You could try this: http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html